# git: list lines added that contain a particular phrase

Tags: git

In git, how can I list for modified and/or staged files all lines **added** that contain a particular keyword?

I feel like git log should be able to do it (or at least be the first step), but the documentation is ... long and my searches aren't helpful today.

On top if it: on windows, and ideally without bash. (I should be able to replace a simple grep with find, though)

purpose: see all the "TODO's" I did add before comitting, ideally in a format like this:

```
c:\src\proj\a.cpp(11):     if(i<0)  // TODO this needs to be more detailed
c:\src\proj\a.cpp(17755): // TODO too many lines in this file
```

Comment: Curious about the reasons for this downvote. Seems like a perfectly legit and interesting question. Did I miss something?

Comment: `git log` walks through existing commits and hence does not inspect the index ("staging area"—the index or staging area holds your proposed *next* commit), nor the work-tree (the third copy of your files, separate from the current commit *and* from the index/staging-area). But `git diff` can compare the current commit to the index, or the current commit to the work-tree, or the index to the work-tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use the `-S` flag**

```
git log --name-only -S "TODO"
```

would list ALL files which ever included that string in the changed lines, which is not exactly what you asked for, but close.

---

For staged files only, try this

```
git diff --staged --name-only -S "TODO"
```

...or alternatively, omit the `--staged` flag to check for unstaged files.

---

Finally, to check both at the same time :

```
git diff --name-only -S "TODO" HEAD
```

(Also, you might want to check the relevant part in the [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt--Sltstringgt))

Comment: Thanks! `git diff -S "TODO" HEAD | findstr ^+ | findstr TODO` already takes this quite far... any idea if it would be possible to preserve full path and original line number? That would allow an output like c:\src\proj\a.cpp(17755): `// TODO too many lines in this file`

Comment: Hmmm...I'm not too sure, I'd have to let more advanced users answer that part.

Comment: `git grep` can number lines, and can search the index (`git grep --cached`) or the work-tree (`git grep` with neither `--cached` nor a commit specifier), Unfortunately this finds *existing* `TODO` lines as well as newly added ones. There's no obvious, easy way get exactly what you want with one single command. I'd probably use `git grep --cached` combined with `git grep HEAD` combined with the Unix/Linux `comm` command for this.